# Extract Text inside Square Brackets into Columns with Excel

Tags: excel, split, formula

I want to split text inside square brackets (6 Text in Square Brackets) in excel using only formula in each cell. Below is the example:

[image]

**I want to make the list like this**
[image]

- Value in A2, I use E2=LEFT(A2;FIND("[";A2)-1)
- Value in B2, I use F2=MID(A2;FIND("[";A2)+1;FIND("]";A2)-FIND("[";A2)-1)
- Value in C2, Manually Copied, Formula ?
- Value in D2, Manually Copied, Formula ?
- Value in E2 & F2 ?

**How to get the other Value using the formula ?**

Comment: try `text to columns`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need E2, F2.  Below is how to replicate what you show in your screen shot above

```
B2:  =SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"[",REPT(" ",256)),(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*255+1,255)),"]","")
```

And Fill right to E2.  Then Select B2:E2 and fill down

You can either hide column A; or you can select/copy B:E ; paste special Values; then delete column A.

Comment: this answered my question. I need E2 & F2 because there are some information I want to add, example: Ragnarok [2004][TV-480p][RaX][Dual][IndoSub]

Comment: @Cheryl Oh, just fill the formula across far enough.  Since it answered your question, please mark my response as the answer.  Thank you.